# What's the best way to modify response data from ApolloQueryResult

Tags: apollo, apollo-client

I am using `watchQuery` to get data from the backend and `subscribe` to the observable. I need to change the data returned from the backend, but they are all read-only property. How can I modify the data?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a `subscription` on an observable you might want to use the `updateQuery` functionality. Example in the [docu](http://dev.apollodata.com/react/subscriptions.html).

There you see that you can update the store using the `subscribeToMore` functionality of your query. Therein you add the `updateQuery` function which gives you the result of the subscription. Now you can copy the result of the subscription update it accordingly and return the updated query.

Comment: docs link changed to https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/basics/queries.html#graphql-query-data-updateQuery